Issue with the UI it works perfectly in web view but make a scroll in mobile view
i created a design it works good in web view but makes a scroll vertically in mobile browser:
web view :
enter image description here
mobile view :
enter image description here
The selfie circled button appears way at the bottom and user needs to scroll all the way down to see it.
i want page ot scroll in mobile view
"use client";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { GrLinkNext, GrLinkPrevious } from "react-icons/gr";
import { MdOutlineCameraAlt, MdFlipCameraAndroid } from "react-icons/md";

// ANT-D :
import { Button, Flex } from "antd";
import { ImageUpload } from "@/services";

const SelfieScan = () => {
  const webcamRef = useRef<Webcam | null>(null);
  //  Url of camera Image will come in this state in base64
  const [capturedImage, setCapturedImage] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const takeSelfieFun = () => {
    if (webcamRef.current) {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
      setCapturedImage(imageSrc);
    } else {
      console.error("Webcam is not ready.");
    }
  };

  const handleRetake = () => {
    setCapturedImage(null);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const imageToUpload = capturedImage ?? "";
    try {
      const data = ImageUpload(imageToUpload);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("------>Error------>", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="selfie-scan-container">
      {capturedImage && showCamera ? (
        <div className="webcam-container">
          <img src={capturedImage} className="webcam" alt="INTERNET ERROR" />
          <Flex gap="20px" className="btn-position">
            <Button
              className="retake-btn"
              onClick={() => {
                setShowCamera(false);
                setCapturedImage(null);
              }}
            >
              <GrLinkPrevious />
            </Button>
            <Button className="retake-btn" onClick={handleRetake}>
              <MdFlipCameraAndroid />
            </Button>
            <Button className="submit-btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              <GrLinkNext />
            </Button>
          </Flex>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <>
          {showCamera && (
            <div className="webcam-container">
              <Webcam
                mirrored
                audio={false}
                ref={webcamRef}
                className="webcam"
                screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
              />

              <div className="btn-position">
                <Button className="camera-btn" onClick={takeSelfieFun}>
                  <MdOutlineCameraAlt />
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </>
      )}
      {!showCamera && (
        <Button onClick={() => setShowCamera(true)}>Tomarse una selfie</Button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelfieScan;

.selfie-scan-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: calc(100vh - 65px);

    .webcam-container {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        gap: 50px;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;

        .webcam {
            height: calc(100vh - 65px);

            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                width: 100vw;
            }
        }

        .btn-position {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 2rem;

            .camera-btn,
            .retake-btn,
            .submit-btn {
                height: 60px;
                width: 60px;
                font-size: 25px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                color: black;
                background-color: #fff;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        }
    }
}

